# Why is using a reserved identifier name in constexpr context not diagnosed?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

Based on the following two rules:

- Using an identifier starting with "_" + capital letter, or containing double underscore, is undefined behavior.
- Undefined behavior is not allowed in constexpr expressions -> compiler should not compile.

Then why aren't compilers complaining about this?

```cpp
constexpr int _UB() {return 1;}
int main() {
    constexpr int a = _UB();
    return a;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7a85xYao8)

Also, I see a lot of professional, MISRA-compliant code that seems to violate this naming rule, see e.g. [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/STMicroelectronics/STM32CubeF7/master/Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F7xx/Include/stm32f732xx.h):

```
#ifndef __STM32F732xx_H
#define __STM32F732xx_H
```

Are all these libs invoking UB too?

Comment: Since I'm too lazy to look it up in standard, here's quote from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers): "Reserved" here means that the standard library headers #define or declare such identifiers for their internal needs, the compiler may predefine non-standard identifiers of that kind, and that name mangling algorithm may assume that some of these identifiers are not in use. If the programmer uses such identifiers, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Where did you get the second rule from? It's incorrect. It shouldn't take a lot of time to come up with as many examples of undefined behavior, which compile just fine, as you wish.

Comment: How to implement [libstdc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/tree/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std) according to your logic? There are underscores and `constexpr` all over there.

Comment: @康桓瑋: libstdc++ already uses thing that would be UB for regular users anyway, so it is not a problem.

Comment: If you misuse a reserved identifier, the program is IFNDR. The standard doesn't have requirements for IFNDR programs. Including: diagnosing certain UB in constexpr context or requiring constant expressions where they are usually required. You don't even reach the stage where you could reason about constexpr things, because IFNDR happens earlier, somewhere at preprocessing phase of translation.

Comment: @Jarod42. I mean, how does the compiler know whether this code comes from the standard library or the user, for example, "*oh, this is libstdc++, so there is no problem.*", or "*this is the user's code, so I should complain about those underscores.*"

Comment: @康桓瑋: Easily, compilers should know its own headers (compilers also provide system include switch). In addition standard headers don't need to be files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Undefined behavior **is not allowed in constexpr expressions** -> compiler should not compile

It's a bit more narrow than this; as per [[expr.const]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.const#5), [/5.7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.const#5.7) in particular:

> An expression E is a core constant expression unless the evaluation of E, following the rules of the abstract machine ([intro.execution]), would evaluate one of the following:
>
> - [...]
> - /5.7 an operation that would have undefined behavior **as specified in [intro] through [cpp]**;

Now, [intro] through [cpp] includes:

> ```
> 1 Scope[intro.scope]
> 2 Normative references[intro.refs]
> 3 Terms and definitions[intro.defs]
> 4 General principles[intro]
> 5 Lexical conventions[lex]
> 6 Basics[basic]
> 7 Expressions[expr]
> 8 Statements[stmt.stmt]
> 9 Declarations[dcl.dcl]
> 10 Modules[module]
> 11 Classes[class]
> 12 Overloading[over]
> 13 Templates[temp]
> 14 Exception handling[except]
> 15 Preprocessing directives[cpp]
> ```

The rule about underscore for global names, however, comes from [library], particularly [[reserved.names]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/reserved.names#2) and [[global.names]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/global.names#1) in [library], which is not covered by "[intro] through [cpp]".

> **[reserved.names]/2** If a program declares or defines a name in a context where it is reserved, other than as explicitly allowed by this Clause, its behavior is undefined.
>
> **[global.names]/1** Certain sets of names and function signatures are always reserved to
> the implementation:
>
> - (1.1) Each name that contains a double underscore __ or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter ([lex.key]) is reserved
>   to the implementation for any use.
> - (1.2) Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the global namespace.

Now, [[lex.name]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/lex.name#3) also includes the same rule for reservation of identifiers

> In addition, some identifiers are reserved for use by C++ implementations and shall not be used otherwise; **no diagnostic is required**.
>
> - (3.1) Each identifier that contains a double underscore __ or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter is reserved to the
>   implementation for any use.
> - (3.2) Each identifier that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the global namespace.

A violation of [lex.name]/3 is ill-formed no diagnostic required (IFNDR), which is not the same as undefined behaviour; as per [expr.const]/5.7 above some UB *should* actually be diagnosed (constexpr contexts).

The limitations of [expr.const]/5.7 to UB as per [intro] through [cpp] is arguably intentionally limiting the rule to avoid constructs that is UB for the typical C++ implementor but not the STL library implementors, e.g. rules in [library]. This could also be a wording defect, particularly as the rules of [lex.name]/3 goes from IFNDR to UB only "after the fact" of [reserved.names]/2 in [library].

Thus, this "kind" of undefined behaviour (UB) does arguably not fall under the UB that disqualifies an expression from being a core constant expression.

Comment: The rule about reserved identifiers in [lex] starting from C++17. And this change was accepted as DR.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Violation of [\[lex.name\]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/lex.name#3) is IFNDR though, and not specified as undefined.

Comment: So, why reason about the place where the requirement comes then?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I've expanded the answer with some [rant] discussion, but yes maybe this could be a wording defect? I could see why requirements (when violated is UB) from [library] is excluded from the [expr.const]/5.7 rule though. Edit: I saw you comment to the question now and yes I agree, if we have IFNDR we can't really argue about any behavior of the program, including UB-diagnostic in core constant expressions.

Comment: I think even if violation of [lex.name]/3 were marked as UB, then constexpr evaluations wouldn't be required to diagnose it, because UB would «happen at lexer level», and the standard would stop imposing any requirement on the behavior of the implementation, way before it reaches the stage where one could speak about what is constant expression and its evaluation. This also means that even though there is UB in [cpp], it would never be «caught» by constant expression evaluation.

Comment: _UB would «happen at lexer level»_ Here I mean violation of the first bullet. The second bullet speaks about «higher level» things, like names, which aren't just single tokens.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I agree. One could ask the question then whether the term "UB" should be removed entirely from the [lex] and [cpp]? If the standard leads us into categorizing "types of UB" (say lexer vs behavior of implementation) it should arguably use two different categories. I don't see what prohibits using only IFNDR for [lex] and [cpp] violations (for those not diagnosable) as opposed to UB; in a simplified view I like to think of IFNDR as a static property of a program, whereas UB is typically a runtime property (odr-violations are harder-to-categorize with that definition, though).