# Can undefined behavior that is explicitly specified occur in a consteval function without a diagnostic

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

Spun off of comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76948726/1013719)

3 [intro.defs], 3.65 [[defns.undef]](https://eel.is/c++draft/defns.undefined) says

> Evaluation of a constant expression ([expr.const]) never exhibits behavior explicitly specified as undefined in [intro] through [cpp]

Though, reading through [[expr.const]](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const) it's not obvious to me that every statement in an immediate function is defined as being a constant expression.

If code in a consteval function attempts behavior explicitly described as UB, can the compiler exhibit UB?

```
consteval void f() {
  int x;
  int y;
  &x - &y;  // UB allowed? or diagnostic required?
}
```

Comment: "_it's not obvious to me that every statement in an immediate function is defined as being a constant expression_": This is never required for any statement in a `consteval` function (at least not by virtue of the `consteval` on the function), but also irrelevant as the answer explains.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If code in a consteval function attempts behavior explicitly described as UB, can the compiler exhibit UB?

No.

We have two rules here:

- A (top-level) call to a `consteval` function must be a constant expression (this rule has become more complicated to spell over the years, my fault, sorry).
- No undefined behavior is allowed during constant evaluation (this one is explicitly ruled out - you're not allowed to evaluate "an operation that would have undefined behavior as specified in [intro] through [cpp], excluding [dcl.attr.assume]" ([[expr.const]/5.8](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#5.8)). This is one of a long list of things you're not allowed to do.

So when you call `f()`, that has to be a constant expression, which requires following all the rules in [[expr.const]/5](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#5). Which the `&x - &y` in there violates. That `f()` fails to be a core constant expression is a mandatory diagnostic, because it's a `consteval` function. The program is ill-formed.

Comment: is this "ill-formed - no diagnostic required" ?

Comment: @ABaumstumpf No. Like I said, it's a "mandatory diagnostic"

Comment: @Barry It would have been IFNDR before your [P2448R2](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2448r2.html), wouldn't it?

Comment: @user17732522 I feel like calling these things IFNDR isn't really meaningful. It's not like an odr-violation, where there is a wide range of behavior you can experience at runtime if you violate that rule. This is just ill-formed code, that the compiler _will definitely diagnose_ if you try to use it, that the compiler used to _also_ be allowed to diagnose even if you don't use it.